# Internet works for ~10 minutes after modem/router reboot, then only pinging works

Tags: router, ping

I recently got a new internet plan with my ISP, and it's been almost completely dysfunctional; browsing only works for the first ten minutes of the router being powered on, and after this I can only access websites by pinging them. Occasionally, some seemingly random websites will also be accessible via browser after the rest of them are gone (this includes Google, backpack.tf and Youtube). This occurs consistently across all devices connected to the network; wired or wifi.

My service provider was also able to confirm this was not due to outages, broken cables or a faulty modem/router (it was replaced twice).

I've also tried netsh winsock reset, ipconfig /flushdns and disabling antivirus/antimalware.

Ipconfig shows these results:

[image: Ipconfig]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do any other PCs work normally using that router?

Comment: What change was made to your service?

Comment: What do you mean by "'only pinging works"? Can you ping internet sites?

Comment: Yes, internet sites and everything else that normally should work responds when I ping it. I'll clarify that in the post. And for future reference - why the downvotes? I feel as if this was a specific and appropriate question.

Comment: Whe you can ping websites but not view them in a browser, are you pinging the IP address or domain name?

Comment: Pinging the domain name. IP works fine as well.

Comment: What is the error you get when trying to view a website?

Comment: Usually just stays loading perpetually or instantly shows a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities. The 2 most likely are an ISP misconfiguration issue (maybe DoS protection) and / or an IP/routing issue.

I would try isolating down to a single computer on your side, and seeing if the problem occurs. If it does, try another computer. The idea here is to see if you have an infected computer sending traffic causing DoS protection to kick in.

There are 2 properties of YouTube and Google which might be helpful in diagnosing the problem (don't know anything of Backpack.tf) - Both Google and YouTube uses QUIC if available  - which uses UDP rather then the standard TCP most other protocols work, and Google has an extensive CDN system which means Google and YouTube traffic is often routed differently.

Answer (score -1):

Right click system tray internet icon and select Troubleshoot Problems.

If that doesn't work try manually setting a different DNS server:

Press Windows key, type network sharing center, click Link under "View your active networks", click properties button, double click "Internet Protocol Version 4", click radio button for "Use the following DNS Server", type 8 in each box, so it's set to 8.8.8.8 which is Google's DNS, click OK until out of all dialog boxes. See if internet works.if so router or isp DNS may be faulty. If it doesn't work then try another router.

Comment: It's probably not a DNS issue because he can still ping the domains.